# How to perform multiple if/else statements against hardcoded interger values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
  sentiment
0 -0.1929
1  0
2  0.3
```

How do I compare every sentiment score in every row in the dataframe against a hardcoded integer and create a new column?

For example:

```
if df.sentiment >= 0.2:
   df['cate'] = 'positive'
elif df.sentiment <= -0.2:
   df['cate'] = 'negative'
else:
   df['cate'] = 'neutral'
```

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
   sentiment      cate
    0 -0.1929     negative
    1  0          netural
    2  0.3        positive
```

I have been trying this piece of code:

```
for row in df_sentences.iterrows():
    if df_sentences['sentiment'] >= 0.2:
        df_sentences['category'] = 'positive'
    elif df_sentences['sentiment'] <= 0.2:
        df_sentences['category'] = 'negative'
    else: 
        df_sentences['category'] = 'negative'
```

but get error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Your else statement will never be reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `np.select`:

```
df['cate'] = np.select([df.sentiment >= 0.2, df.sentiment <= 0.2], ['positive', 'negative'], 'neutral')

>>> df
   sentiment      cate
0    -0.1929   neutral
1     0.0000   neutral
2     0.3000  positive
```

Comment: Should use `np.where` as there is actually only one condition

Comment: `np.where` only allows for a single condition

Comment: @RafaelC when I use np.where, i get error : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,28) (2,) ()

Comment: In this case, that's true that there is only one (valid) condition, but the `elif`/`else` that the OP tried suggests in some cases there will be more conditions

Comment: @user3483203 What are the two conditions in "x>=0.2, x<=0.2" ?

Comment: There is no way to have `np.where` assign either positive, negative, or neutral

Comment: @sacul hm ok, was looking at OP's last if/else block and your answer, maybe your second condition is `x<= - 0.2`? @chris there is now way that np.select yields neutral either